# How do I add Attributes to Tables in Python-Markdown

Tags: python, markdown, pip

Following this documentation:

`http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/attr_list.html`

This works:

```
### This makes a title {: .with-some-class }
```

I need to add classes to tables, but it's not working:

```
| Title | blabla 
-----------------
| foo   | bar {: .with-some-class }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You've discovered an incompatibility between the `attr_list` and `tables` extensions. `<td>` is a block-level element, so by default, `attr_list` looks for the attribute list on the next line, not inline. I think there is a good case for an exception for cell elements (as there currently are for header elements), because there is no way to have multi-line cells with the `tables` extension.

To decide which solution to implement, you'll have to weigh the pain of switching to a new table format with that of switching to a development version of python-markdown.

#### Block Level Solution: use `grid_tables` rather than `tables` (recommended)

Grab [the third-party Grid Tables extension](https://github.com/smartboyathome/Markdown-GridTables), which supports multi-line cells, and put your attribute list it's own line like so:

```
+-------+----------+-------------------------------+
| Title            | blabla                        |
+=======+==========+===============================+
| foo   | bar                                      |
|       | {: class="foo bar" title="Some title!" } |
+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

Output:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" rowspan="1">
<p>Title</p>
</th>
<th colspan="1" rowspan="1">
<p>blabla</p>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
<p>foo
</p>
</td>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="1">
<p class="foo bar" title="Some title!">bar</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

#### Inline Solution: modify `attr_list` to be compatible with `tables`

`attr_list` can support inline attribute lists on cell elements by adding the following lines to attr_list.py:

```
if not m and elem.tag == 'td':
    m = re.search(self.BASE_RE, elem.text)
```

Unfortunately, both of these extensions are part of `extra`, which is built into python-markdown. They rely on internal modules, so making your own extension (compatible with the current pip package) isn't realistic. If you want to implement this solution now, you can install [my fork](https://github.com/ryneeverett/Python-Markdown).

Note: [you cannot leave any space between the cell content and attribute list](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/attr_list.html#inline) (as you did in your question).